# Selectively push part of UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

In the Twitter for iPhone application (the app formerly known as Tweetie) there is nifty effect when pushing from the tweet view controller to the account view controller.

The name of the account, the profile image and the users name stay fixed in position while the  navigation controller animates pushing a new controller on to the stack. Does anyone know how this is achieved?

I've tried pushing a non-animated viewcontroller on to the stack and overriding the viewDidAppear:animated: method but met with no luck.

Comment: Hi Chronos, Are you sure? I just checked it on my 2g iPhone and it looks like the view on the account view controller has the same header fields and that the transition might just appear that they stay where they are.

Comment: I just checked it, I'm pretty sure. In that case, this view would push offscreen, then appear again with the new view. It doesn't here, it remains fixed in place.

Is it possible, that on viewWillDisappear the view is added to [UIApplication sharedApplication] main window (above the navigation controller hierarchy), then removed when the  new view loads? I don't have a chance to test yet, but perhaps this would work?

Comment: I noticed this too, and I think your idea (add it to the `UIWindow` directly) would work... But we won't know until someone tries ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible those view items are not subviews of the viewcontroller's view.  They could be subviews of a higher level view or subviews of the window or another window.